# solar systems "Bow Wave"

Tags: solar-wind, shockwave

could communication with the voyagers eventually be lost due to the solar systems "Bow Wave"  Seems this Bow Wave looks like the one that astronaut's capsule's create upon reentry into earths atmosphere.

Comment: Do you mean the [heliosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliosphere)?

Comment: I suspect he means Bow Shock, but...

Answer (score 3):

Interesting idea. It seems unlikely to me though. So without doing any research:

- if the bow wave was a barrier to radio, we wouldn't be able to to radio astronomy.
- the bow wave has a much lower density than our atmosphere, so plasma effects are going to be much weaker.

More later.